# Templates and Inheritance Filtering

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

Is this use of templates legal?

```
class Foo {};

class Bar : public Foo {};

//Only accept classes, which inherit Foo.
template<Foo T>
void awesomeFunction() {
    Foo *f = new T();
}

int main() {
    awesomeFunction<Bar>();
}
```

Is there another compile-time and exception-safe approach?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you meant `template <class T>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this use of templates legal?

No, because with

```
template<Foo T>
```

you ask for an **object** of type `Foo` as template parameter (and an object of type `Foo` can't be a template parameter) and calling

```
awesomeFunction<Bar>();
```

you pass a **type**, not an object.

The right solution, as showed by Jarod42, is receive a type (`template <typename T>`) and enable/disable the function through SFINAE.

Another way to use SFINAE can be, if you can use at least C++11,

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>{}>::type awesomeFunction() {
    Foo *f = new T();
}
```

that with C++14 can be simplified as

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>{}> awesomeFunction() {
    Foo *f = new T();
}
```

Comment: What about return values? Where do i put the return type specifier?

Comment: @ShroomPow - The return type is the second template parameter for `std::enable_if`; so `typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>{}, void>::type`. But `void` is the default type for the second template parameter so, in your case and ever when the return type is `void`, you can avoid (sorry for the word pun) to explicit it.

Comment: thank you greatly, max66; I'll throw a +1 in the mix.

Comment: it.. it rhymes. ye

Answer (score 3):

You might use SFINAE:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value>* = nullptr>
void awesomeFunction() {
    Foo *f = new T();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With concepts you will be able to write:

```
template<class T>
    requires std::is_base_of_v<Foo, T>
void awesomeFunction()
{
   // ...
}
```

Until they will be part of the standard the SFINAE and static_assert solutions presented in other answers will do.

Comment: Is there a difference when using `requires ` instead of the solution in max66s and Jarod42s answer?

Comment: @ShroomPow - is (IMHO) simpler and more elegant; unfortunately require concept that will be available starting from C++20 (as far I know).

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `is_base_of` type trait with a `static_assert`. If `T` does not derive from `Foo` it will issue a corresponding error message and stop compilation.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename TDerivedFromFoo>
void awesomeFunction()
{
    static_assert
    (
        ::std::is_base_of<Foo, TDerivedFromFoo>::value
    ,   "This function only accept classes, which inherit Foo."
    );
    Foo * f{new TDerivedFromFoo{}};
}
```